# Mysql query with certain IF ELSE If ELSE Conditions

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case

Iam trying to write a mysql query with certain if conditions.

My DB Structure is

Currency (Table)

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | currency | rate
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1      USD       1
2      INR       67.10043
3      GBP       0.761203
4      EUR       0.89295
++++++++++++++++++++++++++

com_payments (Table)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | amt_curr | amt_paid
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1      EUR        300.89
2      GBP        390.90
3      USD        600.00
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The query i am looking for is if

```
if (amt_curr=='USD') {
    $totalinr = (amt_paid * rate); (rate it should take from currency table where currency='USD' from currency table)
} else if ($currency1=='GBP'){
    totalinr = ((select currency, rate from Currency where currency=INR / 0.761203 (GBP value from currency table)) * amt_paid);
} else if ($currency1=='EUR'){
    totalinr = ((select currency, rate from Currency where currency=INR / 0.89295 (EUR value from currency table)) * amt_paid); 
}
```

Iam trying to achieve this with mysql query: I tried something like this but its not working:

```
CASE WHEN (amt_curr=='USD') THEN (amt_paid * rate) (rate it should take from currency table where currency='USD' from currency table)
     WHEN ($currency1=='GBP') THEN ((select currency, rate from Currency where currency=INR / 0.761203 (GBP value from currency table)) * amt_paid) 
     WHEN ($currency1=='EUR') THEN ((select currency, rate from Currency where currency=INR / 0.89295 (EUR value from currency table)) * amt_paid)
END AS totalinr
```

Comment: Anyone to help me on this pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can simply be done with a join, you don't need to use `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.*,
       t.amt_paid /  c.rate
FROM com_payments t
INNER JOIN currency c
 ON(c.currency = p.amt_currency)
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE WHEN c.currency = 'USD' THEN t.amt_paid * c.rate --By the way, you can use only amt_paid since rate is always 1
                                    ELSE t.amt_paid / c.rate
       END
FROM com_payments t
INNER JOIN currency c
 ON(c.currency = p.amt_currency)
```

Comment: I checked the query but i am not getting the desired result. For Example. Iam trying to convert this to INR Values. Iam saving the data in database with base currency as USD. So if the amount is 10 and Currency is USD then totalinr should be 77. ($totalinr = (10 * 67.10043)).  
 
In the case with the query as mentioned by u, i got a result of 1

Comment: @SanjuMenon Then replace `/` with `*` , and shouldn't it be 670 ? `67*10`

Comment: Yes i agreed it is 670. Iam sorry. This is fine with USD. But if the currency selected is other than USD i got a different calculation since the base currency is USD. So can u pls me how to achieve that in a single query.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed, please edit the question and provide expected output from your data sample.

Comment: If you see my CASE statement, i have mentioned that. If the currency is USD, then the calculation is (amt_paid * rate), If the Currency is GBP or any other the calculation is (67.10043 (select currency, rate from Currency where currency=INR) / 0.761203 (gbp rate) * amt_paid)

Comment: So i guess i need to use any kind of if statement or CASE statement. Please let me know

Comment: With little bit changes i could make it work. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a `join`.  In fact, your query is missing a `select`.  I suspect that this does what you want:

```
select p.*,
       p.amt_paid / c.rate
from com_payments p left join
     currency c
     on c.currency = p.amt_currency;
```

This converts all values to US dollars (based on the exchange rates).  You can use similar logic to convert any another currency if you like.

Comment: I will check the same

Comment: I checked the query but i am not getting the desired result. For Example. Iam trying to convert this to INR Values. Iam saving the data in database with base currency as USD. So if the amount is 10 and Currency is USD then totalinr should be 77. ($totalinr = (10 * 67.10043)).

Comment: In the case with the query as mentioned by u, i got a result of 1.